# How do I specify the MySQL root password non-interactively when installing via Aptitude?

Tags: linux, mysql, aptitude

`aptitude install mysql-server` while throw up a prompt asking for me to set the root password. I'd like to avoid this by specifying the password in the initial command. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `debconf-set-selections` manpage - it should do exactly what you're after.

You should be able to go onto a box with MySQL installed already, and do:-

```
debconf-get-selections | grep "^mysql-server" >mysql-server-sel.txt
```

Then copy it to your target box, and run:-

```
debconf-set-selections mysql-server-sel.txt
apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: Thanks Andy for the hint. A previous question seems to have the specific answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/19367/scripted-install-of-mysql-on-ubuntu/19399#19399

Comment: D'oh! Beat me to it ;-)

Comment: No worries. ;-)

Unfortunately `debconf-get-selections` doesn't exist in the version of Ubuntu I'm running, so I'll have to hardcode the keynames.

Comment: Ah - it's in `debconf-utils` - install that and you should be sorted!