# MySQL - don't ask root password when install [debian]

Tags: mysql, debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scripted install of MySQL on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/19367/scripted-install-of-mysql-on-ubuntu)

I wrote script for LAMP auto installation, but it hangs when installs MySQL, because mysql-server asks for new mysql root password. How can I skip this step?
P.S. I use command apt-get install -y mysql-server

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/19367/scripted-install-of-mysql-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can "preseed" the value of any debconf variable (see the manpage for debconf-set-selections; the keys you want are mysql-server/root_password and mysql-server/root_password_again) or, because the question is non-critical, you can skip it by either setting your debconf priority higher or just setting your DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive.